# MongoDB - update a field type in all records

Tags: mongodb

i have a collection of products that i converted from a XLS file, and 
it automatically set all the fields of the product to type string.

Some of them need to be of type int32,
what command in mongo cli can i use to update all records and change their particular fields from type string to type int?

```
{
"_id":"5c3f531baf4fe3182cf4f1ea",
"sku":"7.29002E+11",  => needs to be int32
"product_name":"Example",
"product_cost":"9.261", => needs to be int32
"product_price":"42.7", => needs to be int32
"product_quantity":"245", => needs to be int32
"Warehouse":"4", => needs to be int32
"stamps":[]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From MongoDB 3.4 onwards there is a support for loading the data from csv file into mongoDB by specifying columns data type.
Let' Assume we have data as follows in the csv file

> Student1, 1990-04-23, F, 97, aQDW3qweqwADWDWewed2qewdqeJKKJkDW@43343q3weq
>
> Student2, 1991-03-14, T, 30, akjsdkjbHIH76JKSSDtvtv65easvhudJHCGFL?hjgkjbVJHkj$hjS23

The --fields option specifies which field type mongoimport will use when importing the data into MongoDB.

```
mongoimport --db users --collection contacts --type csv --columnsHaveTypes --fields "StudentName.string(),birthdate.date(2006-01-02),Fail.boolean(),Marks.int32(),imagethumbnail.binary(base64)" --file /example/file.csv
```

Reference for the [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-mongoimport-columnshavetypes)